# Xcode debugger error: use of unresolved identifier 'X' for global variables

Tags: xcode, swift, lldb

Trying to output the value of a global variable in Xcode 6 generates the following error: `use of unresolved identifier 'X'`

Issuing this command is what triggers the error: `expr X`

Local variables work fine.

Is not possible to run `expr` on global variables?

Answer (score 1):

The expression parser can access global variables in general.  For instance:

```
(lldb) expr ((char **) environ)[0]
(char *) $0 = 0x00007fff5fbff88a "YUP=Nope"
```

I had to cast it because we have no debug info for environ...

So lldb must not be finding your symbol.  What do the following say:

```
(lldb) image lookup -n X
```

- this looks for names we have debug info for, and:

  (lldb) image lookup -s X
- this looks through all the symbols for something whose name matches X.

Comment: To clarify, X is available under the self variable, but "expr self.X" generates the same error.

Comment: image lookup -s X returns 1 symbol

Comment: This sounds like a bug.  If you have some code that you can make available to us that shows the issue, please file a bug report with either the lldb bugzilla: https://llvm.org/bugs/ or http://bugreporter.apple.com, and include the code, where to put a breakpoint to see the issue, and how to run the code to hit that breakpoint.